# javaScript:detect whether a user is clicking his smartphone "back"

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to detect whether a user is clicking his smartphone "back" on java script?(not on the browser)?
I mean the physical button at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. You can detect when the user clicks the back button in the browser; clicking the physical back button is supposed to count as the same.

The principle lies in the history API. What you can do is push a "dummy" state on the browser's history stack with no url specified:

```
history.pushState('dummy', null);
```

When the user clicks the back button, this dummy state gets popped, which you can capture as a window-level event:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    console.log('back was pressed!');
    history.pushState('dummy', null);
}
```

Make sure you push a new dummy state after you captured the popstate event.

You can read up on the history API on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History